# Repository vs Domain Services

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, repository, repository-pattern

the more I explore DDD and repositories, the more I feel myself drawn to a domain services approach instead.

Something in my gut doesn't like the fact that a repository (at least in the examples and articles I've been reading) is not single statement atomic.

```
  using (var customerRepository = GetCustomerRepository()) 
  {
      customerRepository.AddCustomerForDelete(someCustomer);
      customerRepository.SaveChanges();
  }
```

There's a bunch of things I just don't like about this. In general, the repository itself becomes a concern and must be maintained (it's IDisposable and requires a "Commit"). It doesn't seem like I'm abstracting persistence concerns all that much.

A much simpler approach that seems to sit better in my gut is:

```
  GetCustomerService().DeleteCustomer(someCustomer);
```

It's atomic. There's no instance of a repository to maintain, dispose, or save changes on. And if you REALLY REALLY need unit of work support outside of a single operation on an aggregate root, incorporate some kind of data scope support (akin to a TransactionScope):

```
 using(var ds = new DataScope())
 {
     // both of these happen under the same underlying DbConnection or whatever
     GetCustomerService().DeleteCustomer(someCustomer1);
     GetCustomerService().DoSomethingElse(someCustomer2);
 }
```

In both of the above, for example's sake, lets say they are in some business controller and the underlying mechanism (sitting inside the repository or service implementation) for data access is an Entity Framework ObjectContext. And a Customer is some aggregate root.

Please show me that a repository approach is better.

Thank you.

Comment: +1; disagree strongly but I like the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that you've only seen naive examples of repository pattern.
There is nothing that says that a repository should have atomic methods.

My approach is pretty much identical to your datascope approach:

```
using(var uow = UoW.Begin())
{
    var customerRepo = new CustomerRepository(uow);
    customerRepo.Remove(someCustomer);
    uow.Commit();
}
```

(My approach is based on Jimmy Nilssons NWorkspace ideas in his book Applying Domain Driven Design and patterns)

This way, I can pass different types of UoW's to my repositories.
e.g. a EF4 based uow or an linq to objects based uow and still use the same linq queries inside the repositories.

Comment: It seems like you've just substituted my concerns with a repository approach with the Unit Of Work.

Comment: Roger addresses a genuine concern with his UoW: "Maintaining a list of objects affected by a business transaction and coordinating the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems." (Fowler). It is the _transactional change_ to _related_ business objects that needs to be addressed in most non-trivial applications.

Comment: In a modern ORM backed data access layer, shouldn't the transactional changes be coordinated by the ORM itself, since, in most cases, a single object/entity graph is being saved?

Comment: Well yes, the UoW is simply an abstraction ontop of the ORMapper. thus allowing different UoW implementations, eg. EF4 and Linq To Object UoW's for production vs. test scenarios.

Comment: But do I really want consuming code mucking around with the UoW? I know I could just inject it into the repository with DI...but it's another concern for the consuming code to overcomplicate things. What's to stop someone from Saving an entity twice in two different repositories, with two different UoWs (which would certainly break with an EF OjbectContext)?